# Rails - Save options into DB (onChange)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm trying to save **options** to DB.

- There is a default value 'nil' and i want to be able to update it by options for (Assignee and Results)
- I'm pulling commits from **BitBucket** and saving into DB

How is the best way to update the DB?
Because I'm not sure how to do that (by a form or there is a different way w/o submiting, like a **onChange**) ?

**MANUALLY UPDATE**

- rails c
- commit = Bitbucket.fist / .last / .find()
- commit.result / .assignee = "1/2/3/4"
- commit.save

**MIGRATION**

```
class CreateBitbuckets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :bitbuckets do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :message
      t.text :date
      t.datetime :remain, :null => false, :default => Time.now
      t.integer :assignee
      t.integer :result

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**VIEW**

```
<% @commits.each do |commit| %>
  <tr class="tableBody">
    <th width="10%" class="author"><%= commit.name %></th>
    <th width="25%" class="message"><%= commit.message %></th>
    <th width="15%" class="date"><%= DateTime.strptime(commit.date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z').strftime("%D %r") %></th>
    <th width="20%" class="timeRem"><%= commit.remain.strftime("%r") %></th>
    <th width="15%" class="assignee">
       <%= select_tag(:assignee, options_for_select([['Ziggy', 1], ['Libor', 2], ['Cam', 3], ['Mike', 4]], commit.assignee))%>
    </th>
    <th width="15%" class="result">
       <%= select_tag(:result, options_for_select([['Waiting', 1], ['Success', 2], ['Broken - Not Submitted', 3], ['Broken - Quick Win', 4]], commit.result))%>
    </th>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Correct answer is here: [Rails - Options saving into DB (onchange)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015677/rails-options-saving-into-db-onchange/37015846#37015846)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this article: http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/advanced-forms

It is much easier to use Rails ERB language for select/options and have the value selected save to an instance variable.  Then, the controller would save the data to the DB through the model.

Comment: It's helpful, just I'm new with databases so if u can help me more with that?
I'm not quite understand how to do that, if i select something how to update it in DB. Definitely i gonna have to set each id have those selections or something similar.